# Passing arguments in the command line in TCL

Tags: tcl

From the [Tcl FAQ for Windows](http://www.tcl.tk/faq/tclwin.htm#sec-4-3):

> To run a console script, invoke the tclsh.exe program, passing it the path to the script file. Any additional arguments on the command line are passed as a list to the script in the argv global variable
>
> ```
> # File printargs.tcl
> foreach arg $::argv {puts $arg}
> ```
>
> We can invoke this script from the command line:
>
> ```
> c:\> tclsh printargs.tcl first "second arg"
> first
> second arg
> c:\>
> ```

I am able to do this.
But how is this working?
How the arguments are going?

**note**: I am a beginner.Sorry If I don't reach the standards.

Comment: The answer is in the first paragraph of your question. It might be a good idea for you to read [the Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what your question is (beyond something that I answer with “the list of arguments after the script name goes in the global `argv` variable”). Please try to explain what part you're having problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand how the call to Tcl works, then you should know that in the following line, two arguments are given, namely **first** and "**second arg**" (The quotes are needed to make sure the 2nd argument consists of two words:

```
c:\> tclsh printargs.tcl first "second arg"
```

Then the following instruction:

```
foreach arg $::argv {puts $arg}
```

...makes use of the control structure:

```
foreach <variable-name> <list> { <commands> }
```

So, **arg** is the variable name (reading this variable requires the addition of a $ sign -> $arg).

The **$::argv** is actually a global variable containing a list of the command line arguments (containing **first** and "**second arg**").

The **puts $arg** is the command to print the contents of the $arg variable to the screen.

But there are probably more simpler examples to start with. If you want to expand your skills, please read some Tcl/Tk tutorials or books. Brent Welch's *Practical Programming with Tcl/Tk* is a good start.